# xcode tab bar controller change selected item with code

Tags: ios, objective-c, xcode

Firstly,I'm using Xcode 6 and Objective-c. I want to change tab bar screen with button or automatically with code how can i do this.Another question may i do this different view not a item of tab bar controller.

```
- (IBAction)backButton:(id)sender
{
    ProfileSide *vc = (ProfileSide *)[[self.tabBarController viewControllers]objectAtIndex:1];
    [vc.view setNeedsDisplay];
    [self.tabBarController setSelectedViewController:vc];
}
```

I tried this code part but not working. ProfileSide name of the class 3rd item tab bar controller.

```
ProfileSide *vc1 = [self.storyboard instantiateViewControllerWithIdentifier:@"meScreen"];
[self presentViewController:vc1 animated:YES completion:nil];
```

Also have got this code part but when i use this one tab bar get disappear.

Comment: firstly yes can do this... another, show us what you have tried so far...

Comment: edited my question you can check

Comment: Only call `-setNeedsDisplay` if you are performing custom drawing inside your view's `-drawRect:` method, and that view needs to redraw its view.

Comment: `ProfileSide *vc = (ProfileSide *)[[self.tabBarController viewControllers]objectAtIndex:1];
    [vc.view setNeedsDisplay];` when i run like this again not work

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
[self.tabBarController setSelectedIndex:yourIndex];
```

Comment: Your code not work than i create UITabBarController class and than i use `self.selectedIndex = 3;` this code part now working...